# Resolve the error while using 'yarn db:start' command

Tags: reactjs, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I am trying to setup a ReactJS workspace in VSCode for [Parabol](https://github.com/ParabolInc/parabol). While executing the command `yarn db:start`, I am receiving the below exception.

```
yarn run v1.22.11
$ docker-compose -f docker/dev.yml up -d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker\api\client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "docker\api\daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "docker\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "docker\api\client.py", line 237, in _get
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http\client.py", line 1255, in request
  File "http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
  File "http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
  File "http\client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
  File "http\client.py", line 950, in send
  File "docker\transport\npipeconn.py", line 32, in connect
  File "docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 23, in wrapped
  File "docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 72, in connect
  File "docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 52, in connect
pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

I am pretty new to ReactJS and have little to no idea on what to do to setup this workspace. Would be much grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Bruce here from Parabol. Thanks for your interest in our app!

For the issue you have seen, can you check:

1. You have Docker up and running
2. You run `yarn db:start` from the root of the repository

Feel free to [create an issue in our repo](https://github.com/ParabolInc/parabol/issues) and we will be more than happy to help you!